# Cómo procesar la respuesta de error en los webservices del SII de la AEAT

Tags: c#, webservice, aeat-sii

Hay algunos casos en los que los webservices del sii devuelven una respuesta de error en formato html (en vez del xml con el esquema de las respuestas).

Por ejemplo, si el certificado no es correcto o el servidor de la aeat está colapsado.

En ese caso, mi aplicación recibe una excepción con este mensaje:

```
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE HTML> ...
```

¿Cómo podría en estos casos leer el mensaje html que devuelve el servidor?

Este es el código:

```
RespuestaLRFEmitidasType resp;
siiSOAPClient clsSiiService;
try
{
  clsSiiService = new siiSOAPClient("SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas");
  clsSiiService.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = oCertificado;
  clsSiiService.Open();
  if (clsSiiService.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
    resp = clsSiiService.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(sumi);
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    clsSiiService = null;
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] (y asi puedes ganar tu primera medalla) y pases por [ask] para aprender como realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, no tengo muy claro si el problema es que recibes un mensaje de error, o que ya que a veces pueden recibirse necesitas poder gestionarlo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la bienvenida. El problema es que en los casos que indico, recibo un mensaje de error porque el servidor no responde utilizando el esquema para las respuestas sino con un texto en html, y como el framework .NET lo recorta a los primeros 1024 caracteres, no puedo averiguar que error ha ocurrido.

Comment: Puedes intentar en el catch `var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();` y consultar resp?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. No tengo acceso a ningún método Response. ex es una Exception, y en resp no llega nada porque la respuesta no es del tipo RespuestaLRFEmitidasType (y por eso salta la excepción).

Comment: En lugar de `catch(Exception ex)` prueba con `catch(WebException ex)` y pones el código de mi anterior comentario.

Comment: Mira [esta pagina de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hola, con catch(WebException ex) no captura la excepción. Debo poner un 
    catch (ProtocolException ex)

Comment: Info de la excepción:
    Exception rethrown at [0]:
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at DemoErrSii.DemoSii.siiSOAP.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasRequest request)
    at DemoErrSii.DemoSii.siiSOAPClient.DemoErrSii.DemoSii.siiSOAP.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(SuministroLRFacturasEmitidasRequest request) in C:\DemoErrSii\Service References\DemoSii\Reference.cs:line 11050

Comment: Puedes comprobar si la `InnerException` es una `WebException`? `if (e.InnerException is WebException)`

Comment: Me devuelve un null en la InnerException   :-(

Comment: Pues entonces lo siento, creo que no puedo ayudarte más ya que no puedo reproducir el error. Tal vez alguien que se maneje con el SII pueda ayudarte mejor...

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema y no consigo ver el mensaje completo del HTML. ¿Pudiste resolverlo? Gracias!

Comment: Hola, sigo sin poder resolverlo  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente como tu dices esto solo ocurre si ha ocurrido algún error grave no capturable como puede ser que el certificado no sirva o el servidor del SII esté caído.

Por desgracia no suelo programar en c#, sino que soy del lado oscuro del php :)

Sin embargo he encontrado esto que habla de un tema similar al tuyo por si te puede ayudar:

https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/wcf-protocolexception/

Traducido su mensaje:

> `ProtocolException` tiene internamente un `WebException` de donde
>   podemos extraer la respuesta completa.

```
public static string ExtractResponseString(this WebException webException)
{
    if (webException == null || webException.Response == null)
        return null;

    var responseStream = webException.Response.GetResponseStream() as MemoryStream;

    if (responseStream == null)
        return null;

    var responseBytes = responseStream.ToArray();

    var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    return responseString;
}
```

> Así lo uso en mi programa:

```
using (var client = new Service1Client())
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(client.DoWork());
    }
    catch (ProtocolException e)
    {
        var webException = e.InnerException as WebException;

        var responseString = webException.ExtractResponseString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseText))
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

> Y ahora obtengo la respuesta completa. Hay demasiado texto pero al
>   menos puedo entender cual es el problema que tengo.

Espero que esto pueda servir en tu caso. Comentarte también que aunque no domino c#, en php he redactado un ebook tutorial en http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ con ejemplos de código que cubren todo el circuito de comunicación con el SII donde se puede ver como obtener la respuesta en objeto de PHP, texto plano, o XML.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta.
Había llegado a comprobar que el tipo de Exception era ProtocolException.
Ahora acabo de probar el ejemplo que me has indicado, pero desafortunadamente el InnerException que me llega es null, así que sigo sin poder leer el contenido completo de la respuesta en html.
Estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2015 y .NET 4.5.
No sé si en versiones anteriores (el ejemplo es de 2012) se comportaba de otra manera.
De todos modos, gracias por la ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: Pues lo siento.. quizás probar en la versión de inglés con tu ejemplo de código más reciente te encuentres con más gente que pueda tener una respuesta válida.